# multiple id selector using fliter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, multiple-select, multipleselection

Now i have two divs with different id (`#filter1`, `#filter2`).
I want the selection inside div (`.tags`) can change the result of (`#filter1`, `#filter2`) at the same time.

I have tried to use multiple id selector, but seems cannot work.

```
$(function(){
$('#filter1, #filter2').filter();
});
```

additionally, i would like to set while i selected D1, the multiple selection of D2 will be disabled
it can just switch the option from D1 to D2 if i click D2
(as they are in the same catagory)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/co2kwan/gme8z/1/)

i am a beginner on js, hope can get help from you

many thanks

Comment: [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/co2kwan/gme8z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using "each()". See following script:

```
$("#filter1,#filter2").each(function(){
    $(this).filter();
});
```

Comment: thanks~ now i make the two divs work together, but i can't disable the multiple selection of D2~ please help

Comment: You have seen that to select multiple IDs together we have used

$("#filter1,#filter2").each(function(){
//put your action here using "$(this)"
 });

This works same like foreach statement.

Answer (score 0):

So to disable using multiple selectors, you can get it by this:

```
$("#filter1,#filter2").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Select the check if it is useful to you ;)